# How to find out the current running test

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest for running my test methods. And i am trying to implement a log file for each test method.

consider the following test module with test methods.

```
#content of test_module.py
def test_1(log):
    log.info('inside test_1')
    util.abc(log)


def test_2(log):
    log.info('inside test_2')
    util.abc(log)
```

The content of my util module is:

```
#content of util.py module
def abc(log):
    # perform some logic here and calculate result.      
    log.info('the value is: %s' % result)
```

And here is my conftest.py file.

```
#conftest.py
@pytest.fixture()
def log(request):
    test_path = request.node.parent.name.strip(".py")
    test_name = request.node.name
    node_id = request.node.nodeid
    logs_dir = pkg_resources.resource_filename("test_results", "logs")
    log_file_path = '%s/%s' % (logs_dir, test_path)
    if not os.path.exists(log_file_path):
        os.makedirs(log_file_path)
    logger_obj = logger.make_logger(test_name, log_file_path, node_id)
    yield logger_obj
    handlers = logger_obj.handlers
    for handler in handlers:
        handler.close()
        logger_obj.removeHandler(handler)
```

The test module test_module.py is located under tests/ directory. So, when i run the tests using py.test tests/ it executes the test_1 and test_2 methods and logs the test specific info under test_results/ directory into a log file specific to each test. test_1.log and test_2.log.

This works for me. But, the problem is that i had to pass log object from the test methods to each method that i call from the test method.

In this example when i am calling the util.abc method i am passing the log object from the test method. So, the method abc inside the util module knows which log file to log to. But, i don't want to pass in the log object this way to all the methods that i call from test methods. I believe there should be a better way. I am thinking, if there is a way to find out which test method called the method abc then i don't have to pass in the log object this way. Anyone knows on how to figure this out? or any other ideas to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always create `logger` module. In your test methods, you will assign `log` to `logger.log`

```
#content of test_module.py
def test_1(log):
    logger.log = log
    log.info('inside test_1')
    util.abc()

def test_2(log):
    logger.log = log
    log.info('inside test_2')
    util.abc()
```

and in your normal methods just call it

```
def abc():
    # perform some logic here and calculate result.      
    logger.log.info('the value is: %s' % result)
```

Comment: I think this would work if i run my tests sequentially. But, i am planning on running them in parallel.

Comment: @sridhar249 I've never run pytests in parallel but if it's based on multiprocessing (it's likely; not multithreading) then I think they shouldn't share `logger.log`.

Comment: @sridhar249 I've checked documentation https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist and all is based on subprocesses so the solution should works.

Comment: If i understand it correctly, logger.log = log inside the test method is assigning the log object that is passed as parameter to the test method to log variable inside the logger module. I think this will not work well when i run the tests in parallel, as the log variable inside the logger module can only hold one instance at a time. So, test_1 would have initialised the logger.log and while test_1 is still running, test_2 would have initialised logger.log to something else.  So, if test_1 calls util.abc() at this time, then it would get logger to test_2's logfile. right?

Comment: You've understood the concept perfectly. But if you run it in parallel, 4 tests at the same time for example, then pytest-xdist creates 4 subprocesses. Every subprocess is independent of another one, so the situation you've described won't appear. The thing you are afraid of will happen if running tests is based on concurrency, not parallelism - multithreading, not multiprocessing. Multithreading is used to keep your application responsive for a user, multiprocessing - to getting things like running tests done at quick time. As I checked in a documentation, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @sridhar249 Let me give you an example. You got 4 processes - number one runs `test_1` and `test_2`, number two `test_3` and `test_4` and so on. Tests are executing sequentially in each process. But processes runs in parallel. And each process has his own `logger.log`. That's it, buddy.

Comment: you are awesome. Thank you so much!